# While loop not looping for file contents

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have a function

```
function abc{
 a=$1
 b=$2
 if [[ $a == $b ]]then;
  return 0
 else
  return 1
 fi
}
```

I am using the function inside while loop

```
 check="mystring"
 while IFS= read -r val; do
   echo "-----------------------${val}"
   if ! abc "${val}" "${check}"; then
     echo "${val} Failure " >> $OUTPUT_LOG_FILE
   else
     echo "${val} Success " >> $OUTPUT_LOG_FILE
   fi
 done <my_list.txt
```

where as my list.txt content are as follows:

```
somestring
otherstring
mystring
```

The problem is it's just looping through 1st variable and not looping others.

Comment: What do you mean by "first variable"? If you mean the first line in my_list.txt, I can confirm that the program works on my Ubuntu 16 server, performing three loops.

Comment: @berndbausch  You must have fixed some syntax to get this to run at all ?

Comment: Fix the obvious syntax errors and it works fine

Comment: In any case, it'd make things easier for testers if you posted a _full_ script along with the output. That way everyone trying to help you doesn't have to go through the trouble of  piecing together the script from parts etc.

Comment: I fixed a few syntax errors like missing spaces. Without those fixes, it didn't run at all.

Comment: Make sure the text file does not have `\r\n` line endings: `"mystring\r" != "mystring"`

Answer (score 0):

Your script throws seven errors flagged in `shellcheck`, so this is not what you are running. Each of the error codes has a detailed description, like: `github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC1095`

Also, all the expansions within `abc` should be quoted.

I'm not clear what value `abc` adds to the script. Writing the test inline is shorter than even calling the function.

```
$ shellcheck -s bash -
function abc{
 a=$1
 b=$2
 if [[ $a == $b ]]then;
  return 0
 else
  return 1
 fi
}
check="mystring"
 while IFS= read -r val; do
   echo "-----------------------${val}"
   if ! abc "${val}" "${check}"; then
     echo "${val} Failure " >> $OUTPUT_LOG_FILE
   else
     echo "${val} Success " >> $OUTPUT_LOG_FILE
   fi
 done <my_list.txt

In - line 1:
function abc{
            ^-- SC1095: You need a space or linefeed between the function name and body.
            ^-- SC1009: The mentioned parser error was in this brace group.


In - line 4:
 if [[ $a == $b ]]then;
 ^-- SC1049: Did you forget the 'then' for this 'if'?
 ^-- SC1073: Couldn't parse this if expression.
                  ^-- SC1010: Use semicolon or linefeed before 'then' (or quote to make it literal).

In - line 6:
 else
 ^-- SC1050: Expected 'then'.
     ^-- SC1072: Unexpected keyword/token. Fix any mentioned problems and try again.
```